# jquery slider: how to separate two slider collection to act independently?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a javascript slider that works perfectly fine when it is the only slider on the page.

But when i have a second slider it reacts to the controls from the other slider.

my javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    var slideCount = $('.slider ul li').length;
    var slideWidth = $('.slider ul li').width();
    var slideHeight = $('.slider ul li').height();
    var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

    $('.slider').css({ width: slideWidth*4, height: slideHeight });

    $('.slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

    $('.slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('.slider ul');

  function moveLeft(anchor) {
      $(anchor).parent(".slider ul").animate({
          left: +slideWidth
      }, 200, function() {
          $('.slider ul li:last-child').prependTo($(anchor).parent(".slider ul"));
          $(anchor).parent(".slider ul").css('left', '');
      });
  }

  function moveRight(anchor) {
      $(anchor).parent(".slider ul").animate({
          left: -slideWidth
      }, 200, function() {
          $('.slider ul li:first-child').appendTo($(anchor).parent(".slider ul"));
          $(anchor).parent(".slider ul").css('left', '');
      });
  }

  $('a.control-prev').click(function () {
      moveLeft($(this));
  });

  $('a.control-next').click(function () {
      moveRight($(this));
  });

});
```

my HTML:

```
<h1>Slider Collection 1</h1>
<div class="slider">
  <a href="#" class="control_next">></a>
  <a href="#" class="control_prev"><</a>
  <ul>
    <li>SLIDE 1</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
    <li>SLIDE 3</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 4</li>
    <li>SLIDE 5</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 6</li>
    <li>SLIDE 7</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 8</li>
  </ul>  
</div>

<h1>Slider Collection 2</h1>
<div class="slider">
  <a href="#" class="control_next">></a>
  <a href="#" class="control_prev"><</a>
  <ul>
    <li>SLIDE 1</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
    <li>SLIDE 3</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 4</li>
    <li>SLIDE 5</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 6</li>
    <li>SLIDE 7</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 8</li>
  </ul>  
</div>
```

How can i achieve that the click on the next/prev link of the first slider collection doesn't have an effect to the second slider collection and vice versa?

Thanks to user Leopard i updated my javascript. But the slider doesn't work anymore. How can i fix it?

I updated the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chojo/mfj7np6f/2/)

Comment: You have an invalid HTML code. Change the IDs of the second one. Multiple selector in js. Like this $('#slider, #slider2').event();

Comment: thanks, i updated my demo from css id slider to css class slider but it still doesn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/chojo/mfj7np6f/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given both slider `divs` same `id` `id="slider"` so it is causing the other slider to move as well when you click on next prev.

You can bind click on `class` and move the respective `slider`.

Here is a complete working solution

**HTML**

```
<h1>Slider Collection 1</h1>
<div id="slider" class="slider">
  <a href="#" class="control_next">></a>
  <a href="#" class="control_prev"><</a>
  <ul>
    <li>SLIDE 1</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
    <li>SLIDE 3</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 4</li>
    <li>SLIDE 5</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 6</li>
    <li>SLIDE 7</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 8</li>
  </ul>  
</div>

<h1>Slider Collection 2</h1>
<div id="Div1" class="slider">
  <a href="#" class="control_next">></a>
  <a href="#" class="control_prev"><</a>
  <ul>
    <li>SLIDE 1</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
    <li>SLIDE 3</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 4</li>
    <li>SLIDE 5</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 6</li>
    <li>SLIDE 7</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 8</li>
  </ul>  
</div>
```

**Javascript/Jquery**

```
var slideCount = $('.slider ul li').length;
var slideWidth = $('.slider ul li').width();
var slideHeight = $('.slider ul li').height();
var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;
$(function () {



    $('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth*4, height: slideHeight });

    $('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });

    $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');



    $('a.control_prev').click(function () {

        moveLeft($(this));
    });

    $('a.control_next').click(function () {
        moveRight($(this));
    });

});    



function moveLeft(anchor) {

    $(anchor).parent().find("ul").animate({
        left: +slideWidth
    }, 200, function() {
        $(anchor).parent().find('ul li:last-child').prependTo($(anchor).parent().find("ul"));
        $(anchor).parent().find("ul").css('left', '');
    });
}

function moveRight(anchor) {

    $(anchor).parent().find("ul").animate({
        left: -slideWidth
    }, 200, function() {
        $(anchor).parent().find('ul li:first-child').appendTo($(anchor).parent().find("ul"));
        $(anchor).parent().find("ul").css('left', '');
    });
}
```

Comment: have you given your divs with class `slider`.